# Change the menu home link to something else

Tags: menus, homepage

I'm using the built in menu system, and I wan't to change the text of the home menu link to something else, like "hjem", and i have tried placing this in the code:

```
<?php wp_page_menu( array( 'show_home' => 'Hjem', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order' ) ); ?>
```

But that did nothing but show the menu, with the home menu text "Home".

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily enough, I see the same behavior in WordPress 3.4.2 and 3.5-beta2. No plugins active, theme TwentyEleven.

***Even setting*** `show_home` as `false` will show the *Home* button ?!

Checking the core, I see this filter that does the trick:

```
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'wpse_70551_change_page_menu');

function wpse_70551_change_page_menu($args) {
    $args['show_home'] = "Hjem";
    return $args;
}
```

**[Update]**
This was a [bug with the Bundled Themes](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22331).

> The culprit is `twentyeleven_page_menu_args()`
>   (`twentytwelve_page_menu_args()` in Twenty Twelve).
>
> It ignores any passed value and enforces true instead:
>   http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php#L372
>
> [22331.patch](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/22331/22331.patch)​ is a fix for all three themes.